# PHP PDO: Object auto-deconstructs after calling function

Tags: php, jquery, oop, object, pdo

I've got a situation, where the object created in the top position in my PHP file, gets deconstructed before reaching the end of the PHP code on that file

***File1.php***:

```
//* This is all in the same PHP file *//

<?php
    session_start();
    include 'includes/user.inc.php';

    $userOBJ = new User; //Declaring the object
?>

//*** jQuery and HTML code here ***//

<?php
    if($userOBJ->isAdmin($_SESSION['session_u-name']) == true){
        AdminControl();
    } 

    // This code gets done without any problem

    function AdminControl(){
        echo "<a id='dbControlAdmin' onclick='changeDisplayAdm()'>Database 
        Control</a>";
    }
?>

//*** More HTML and jQuery Code here ***//

<?php
   $userOBJ->getUsersName(); //The object is no longer available when reaching this code
?>
```

*In the Object Class I have this function as the deconstructor:*

```
public function __destruct(){
        echo "<b style='color: red;'>Status:</b> Database Connection->Disconnect";
    }
```

*This are the functions that are called through the Object:*

```
    public function isAdmin($user){
    $userToGet = $user;

    $stmt = $this->Connect()->prepare("SELECT admin_db FROM user_secure WHERE username_db=?");
    $stmt->execute([$userToGet]);
    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
        $value = $row["admin_db"];
            if($value == 1){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    }
}

public function getUsersName(){
    $stmt = $this->Connect()->prepare("SELECT username_db FROM user_secure");
    $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo "<option value='" . $row['username_db'] . "'>" . $row['username_db'] . "</option>";
        }
}
```

}

When I run the website, in the top left corner appears this message

> Status: Database Connection->Disconnect

Which is the instruction that the object has in the __destruct function, and the website deploys a PHP error where that last function call is: `$userOBJ->getUsersName();`

The error is:

> Notice: Undefined index: username_db in C:\wamp64\www\NewKali\includes\user.inc.php on line 57

I don't get where the __destruct function is called or why it is called! Hope that you can help me.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***OWNER EDIT:***

I changed `$row['username_db']` to `$row["username_db"]` and it worked... (Also changed a few other things)

My final code in the function was this:

```
public function getUsersName(){
    $stmt = $this->Connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_secure");
    $stmt->execute();

    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
        $value = $row["username_db"];
        echo "<option value='" . $value . "'>" . $value . "</option>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to point out: the change that did it for you was `while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) ...` to `foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) ...`. The other changes didn't change anything. You could have also changed it to `while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) ...` (which is probably what you were trying to do in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

rename column `username_db` into a column, which actually exists on the server.

Comment: I don't seem to fully understand this, but this column does exists in the server: http://prntscr.com/ljortv

Comment: @AlanMaldonado try `print_r($row)`. that might be an empty `array`. `0` results doesn't have column names. so you need to check for `sizeof($row) > 0`.

Comment: Okay, So I've changed my code in that function to this: https://3v4l.org/8eHpI and when I run the website, it tell deploys this: http://prntscr.com/ljowuz 
___ So this means that the array is 0, but I don't get why, because my table is populated and I think the query is right... What do you think?

Comment: OMG I found the error... I believe everything in my code is correct, but somehow it isn't...

Comment: @AlanMaldonado I merely wonder, why you use `prepare`, without `?`... the query is so simple, that there is no need to prepare the statement. `query` should suffice - and might return results.

Comment: I'm still learning PDO, so I applied every SQL request to PDO, even the ones that had no point to convert them, sorry!

Answer (score -1):

You're setting `$userOBJ = new User` twice.

Comment: I was aware of this, and removing it did nothing :( It's still the same

Comment: It's not a request for clarification or a critque, it is one of the causes for his error (according to his response there is a second cause). Setting the same variable again calls the destructor of the previous object.